# Rails chat app: “ReferenceError: Faye is not defined”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, faye

I am following a tutorial to make a simple chat app with Rails and it uses Faye a publish and subscribe system.

I added the gem to the `Gemfile`, as well as a server that supports `Faye`:

```
gem 'faye-rails', '~> 2.0'
gem 'thin'
```

And installed them with `bunlde install`.

I set the server up in the `config/application.rb` configuration file:

```
config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock
config.middleware.use FayeRails::Middleware, mount: '/faye', timeout: 25
```

Here's where I am using Faye:

`comments.coffe`:

```
window.client = new Faye.Client('/faye/client.js')

jQuery ->
    client.subscribe '/comments', (payload) ->
        $('#comments').find('.media-list').prepend(payload.message) if payload.message
```

And I required this file and faye in the main `application.js` file:

```
//= require faye
//= require comments
```

The problem is the messaging system is not working instantly as expected, it works as a publish/subscribe chat system but as a polling system rather, as it takes a couple of seconds for new comments to render.

I suspect the problem is this error that Firefox notices in the `comments.js` file:

```
ReferenceError: Faye is not defined
```

I don't get it. It **is** defined, since if it weren't no comments at all would be rendered.

I am not familiar with Faye or any publisher-subscriber system so I am not sure I am missing a key step.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi. You fixed your issue, if yes, how? I have same error.

Comment: @StefanHansch I did not. I used another gem built on top of `faye`, it's called `private_pub` (https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub). I did this tutorial in particular: http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails